# Tumblr Pages Menu and Social Buttons Not showing up in mobile

Tags: css, mobile, tumblr

I am customizing this Tumblr for someone who asked that I move the menu items above the header, including social buttons. I solved this in the Effector theme by selecting "Pages in top bar" (which moved the Music, Gallery, and Contact buttons on the top left) and then opted to forego the social widgets in the theme and instead linked images of select social buttons to the musician's social sites. It looks exactly how I want it to look on a computer, but this top "menu" disappears in mobile view. I'm not quite sure what I need to input in CSS, or maybe that's not the route to go. Tried various things for a few days to no avail. Anyone know of a solution?

Site: sinclaireoo.com

Comment: Is there a code snippet or something that you would be able to post?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to customize > advanced options and click "Use optimized mobile layout"?

Comment: Pretty sure this will turn out to be the correct answer.